# Split long string into byte arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

This is for the level system in a game.
The level consists of two byte arrays:
`byte[] tiles` and `byte[] data`
`tiles` holds the id of the tiles and `data` holds data.

I created a function to make a string out of them. It's formatted like `tileId:tileData,tileId:tileData,tileId:tileData,etc`
You can see an example of a complete level here: http://pastebin.com/X2LG7e80

The script looks like this:

```
public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int t = 0; t < tiles.length; t++) {
        sb.append(tiles[t]).append(":").append(data[t]).append(t == tiles.length - 1 ? ";" : ",");
    }
    s = sb.toString();
    return s;
}
```

Now I need a way to turn it back into two byte arrays.
I tried a couple of different things but none of them worked.

Comment: The way you've described this program, it sounds like each data value is a single byte.  Is that accurate?  I can imagine tile IDs being a single byte, but the data for each tile being a single byte is surprising.

Comment: "I tried a couple of different things but none of them worked." - Can you post some of the attempts you have made?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a variable `stringRep` contains the string representation:

```
String stringRep = "tileId:tileData,tileId:tileData,tileId:tileData";


String[] pairs = stringRep.split(",");
byte[] tiles = new byte[pairs.length];
byte[] data = new byte[pairs.length];

int i = 0;
for(String pair : pairs){
    String[] pairParts = pair.split(":");
    titles[i] = Byte.parseByte(pairParts[0]);
    data[i] = Byte.parseByte(pairParts[1]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: no problem, be sure to mark the green check box and select this as the right answer if it worked for you.